# Jmeter : Responce Error

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have recorded the script in jmeter. after recording i run that script and save the result in view result tree listener. In result Responce data showing me following for every sampler request

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <server_response>
<redirect><![CDATA[http://192.168.0.107/maximo/webclient/login/logout.jsp?timeout=true]]></redirect>
</server_response>
```

Why server responce showing me timeout for every sampler? M I doing wrong recording or what is the issue? please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Either your jmeter test plan is dodgy or you have missed parameterization after your recording.

Best place to start debugging,

> http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

- Did  you change anything in the recorded http requests?
- Could you provide your actual test plan structure?
- Are you capturing and setting the dynamical values for each thread?

Comment: Could you show the http response? I am guessing that you are not holding the same session, and web client just throws you out.

Comment: Oh I see timeout=true; You did not put session cookie manager or your viewState (if the app is with primefaces) or similar parameter is missing or wrong.

Comment: How can I hold same session ? If I want to run script for many user then how can I change session id for each user ? i  tried correlation but its not working.

Comment: Session cookie manager take cares of the session toruble without any coding. Could you show an example of what have you tried?